# SQL Server Backup Transaction log in online

Tags: sql-server

I am going to take backup (.bak) of transaction log of my database. Will it cause any problems if i take it in online means the same time all other database activities will happen (insertion, update, delete, select)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can safely perform a transaction log backup without affecting your live database activity. This link provides restrictions for doing this kind of backup - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179478.aspx#Restrictions, of which there are none of note.

Backing up the log with not block running transactions.